# Number of users, or "am I going crazy"

Tags: discussion, users

We are currently hovering near 5000 registered users, so I've been monitoring the user page. As context, 5000 users corresponds to a little under 139 pages of users, at 36 to a page.

Here's what's been happening for the last month or so:

- user page lists 137 pages
- 137th page has some number < 36 of users listed. That number steadily increases till about 30-31
- all users disappear from that page, and it goes back down to 2-3 (sometimes the page itself goes away, and we revert back to 136 pages).
- repeat.

Now I understand that users can remove their accounts at any time, and so the number of users is not an increasing function of time, but this seems a little strange. I know that early in the new rendering process there was some problem with how users were counted, and I wonder if there's some bug that has been observed ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be that old inactive accounts are being culled. If you aren't familiar with our abandoned account culling rules, read about it at

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

Comment: that could very well be. Thanks for the link.