# Number of users approaching 5000

Tags: discussion

The number of users on the site is approaching 5000. There's no question here really, but there's no other way of drawing attention to this fact :).

Right now we're about 12 short. Note that [as per this question](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/number-of-users-or-am-i-going-crazy), extremely inactive user accounts are being removed, so while I make no claim that there are even 1000 ACTIVE users, the number is less meaningless than it used to be :).

Note that there are about 340 users with score above 200 (which is the benchmark SE used to determine transition from beta).

**Update**: we just crossed the 5000 mark. so I'm closing this question now :)

Comment: I guess that your question is “Is there any comment on this?”

Comment: Can we get data about our users, e.g. number of users who visit every week?

Comment: I don't know if such analytics are available. as a mod, I have access to some tools, but not this kind.